# How to send a message in broadcast from a simple module to cars moving around in omnet ++?

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet, sumo

I want my edge module which is a simple module in my case to send an alert ( a message ) to the cars moving around ( which are compound adhochost modules ) , can you please tell me how to do that ? i have been searching for days with no result ! Thank you in advance !

Comment: The correct answer to this question will no doubt depend on which software (and which software versions) you are using. Without that information, it is very hard to help.

Comment: Thank you for answering me , i am using omnet 5.6.2 under a virtual box ( vmware installed automatically by vagrant ) , i want an edge station which i defined like a simple module to send a message in broadcast to all mobile vehicles around ( i am using a customized map in sumo in parallel ) , the vehicles are configured exactly the same as the veins_inet example vehicles ( where there is the square shape and a car that alerts about an accident  ) , so they are adhochost vehicles , the difficulty for me lies in how to send a message from this edge which is a simple module to mobile vehicles  ?

Comment: Which software versions of Veins and of the INET Framework are you using?

Comment: veins version is : 5.1 and inet version is 4.2